# Microsoft-Edge's command-line option "--load-extension" does not working

Tags: command-line, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I want to load the temporary extension when you open the browser.

But the command for **Microsoft Edge does not work**.
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --load-extension="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\autoLogin"`

The command for **Chrome works**.
`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --load-extension="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\autoLogin"`

What should i do?

Comment: I tested the above command and found that it is also not loading the extension for Google Chrome. The command also did not work for Edge. Could you show the exact command that works for Chrome? Besides, you could add the above line to the Edge shortcut like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --load-extension="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test-extension"` it works for me.

Comment: The command worded for Chrome is `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --load-extension="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\autoLogin"`.

Comment: The command for Edge `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --load-extension="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\autoLogin"` is not work, and it does not work too that i add to the Edge shortcut.

Comment: Could you please share which Windows OS and which version of the Edge browser you are using? You could right-click the Edge shortcut and add `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --load-extension="<extension-path>"` to the Target field and click OK. As an alternative, you could goto `edge://extensions/` and click the `Load unpacked` button, and select your extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested further on my side and found that the below command loads the extension to the Edge browser.

```
start msedge --load-extension="<Extension-path>"
```

Output:

[image]

Note: Make sure to close all the instances of the Edge browser before running this command.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But the `NASA Picture Extension` is not the extension `test-extension` that you want to load with the command ?

Comment: **NASA picture of the day viewer** is the Extension name. The extension name is stored in the `Manifest.json` file. **test-extension** is just a folder name of the extension. You could notice that in the command, we need to pass the extension path, not the extension name.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. It works when start with all background processes closed.